# Shortcut to go to file layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

**In Window OS**, I can open file .xml layout from file .java by shortcut **Ctrl + Alt + Home**.

Does anyone know shortcut same **in Mac OS** ?

Comment: Can you post screenshots of before and after effect.

Comment: @RahulKhurana before: not open. After: open. Lol

Comment: @TimCastelijns I really don't get the OP question. So I just asked for some screenshots

Comment: if your cursor is over the R.layout.xml line then you can use `Command + B` to go to declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to File |> Settings |> Keymap |> Main Menu |> Navigate

There you should have the option **Related Symbol**...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Command + F12 should do the trick.